# Move relation to other Node, by pattern in Neo4j with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to combine Housenumber nodes, that are attached to a ZipCode node.

[image: Graph with duplicate Housenumbers pointing to a ZipCode]

I run this query to visualize this graph.

```
MATCH path=(z:ZipCode)-[:NUMBER_IN_ZIPCODE]->(h:House)<--()
WHERE z.zipcode = "3014GE" AND h.number = "75"
RETURN path
```

So I want the Street node that is now pointing to a `Housenumber` node,
be pointing to the `Housenumber` that haves the `WORKS_AT` relations.

How I can move the relation `NUMBER_IN_STREET` to that node?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about a graph refactoring. Since there is no possibility to do it easily with the help of a cipher, take a look at external tools and plugins. For example, [apoc](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_refactoring):

---

- Merge nodes onto first in list

  `call apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([node1,node2])`

---

- Redirect relationship to use new end-node

  `call apoc.refactor.to(rel, endNode)`

Comment: is there a cypher way to do those i.e. with no library... asking cause i'm using radisgraph